# Unexpected token '{' while rendering partials in EJS

Tags: ejs

I am rendering some basic stuff (a header and a navBar) with the help of EJS and load different menus according to a variable, but I hit the wall with an error that I don't quite understand.

the error says:

```
SyntaxError: Y:\Basic\Section35\364\views\comments\index.ejs:2
    1| <%- include('../partials/head') %>
 >> 2|     <%- include('../partials/navBars') %>
    3|         <div class="row row-cols-auto g-3 align-items-center">
    4|             <div class="col-12">
    5|                 <div class="container mt-3">

Unexpected token '{' in Y:\Basic\Section35\364\views\partials\navBars.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
```

in my index.js I have

```
app.get('/comments', (req, res) => {
    title = "/Comments/index.ejs";
    res.render('comments/index', { title, comments });
})
```

at the bottom of my navBar.ejs I have:

```
.
.
</nav>
<div class="container">
    
    <% if(title==="/Comments/index.ejs"){ %>
        <div class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-10">
                <h1><%=title%></h1>
            </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-2 mx-auto">
                <a href="/comments/new" class="btn btn-primary">Create</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <% } eles{%>
        <div class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center">
            <div class="col-10">
                <h1><%=title%></h1>
            </div>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-2 mx-auto">
                <a href="../comments/" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
            </div>
    
        </div>
    <%}%>
```

and in my index.ejs I include the navBar after I include headers like:

```
<%- include('../partials/head') %>

    <%- include('../partials/navBars') %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be because you spelled `else` as `eles`.

Comment: wow, you are right...I'm ashamed of myself !!!

Comment: @Ali Haha, happens to the best of us, sauce me an upvote if it helped ;)